# Target estimate term in Firebase Push Notification shows "-"

Tags: firebase, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

I was sending push notifications to my app using Firebase notifications console.

Since last few messages it shows that

`"target estimate s - "`  and notifications are not working

previous messages it was showing

`"target estimates <1000 "`  and notifications are working

Why are my notifications not sent?

Comment: I also have a "-" in my target estimate but it works just fine.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Resolved by installing gapps and google play services in the device.